# Vue.js remove event listener without function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, addeventlistener

I added a event listener to my document like this:

```
deleteTask(event){
     // myFunc
}

created() {
     document.addEventListener("keypress", this.deleteTask);
},
```

This happened in my **Home.vue** component.
Now i want to remove this event listener in my **Card.vue** component.
Like so:

```
document.removeEventListener("keypress", this.deleteTask);
```

This obviously doesn't work since **this.deleteTask** is not known in the Card.vue component. But i need the deleteTask func to stay in my Home.vue cause it operates on some arrays there. So my question is now: 
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an [EventBus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/).

Create a new `js` file with:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Now you can in your **Home.vue** listen to events:

```
created() {
   ...
   EventBus.$on('removeListener', () => { document.removeEventListener("keypress", this.deleteTask); })
}
```

The event `removeListener` will then be called in **Card.vue** using `EventBus.$emit('removeListener')`

Comment: Do i have to manage some imports to make this work? because im getting a error that EventBus is not defined in my Home.vue

Comment: Yes, you will have to `import { EventBus } from 'path/to/js'` in both components

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it global, let it to listen only in your component:

```
<template>
  <div @keypress="deleteTask">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: But how do i then remove the task from my array which is in my Home.vue component? The problem is that i have a Home.vue component which holds a list component and this than holds a cardlist component and than a card component